# Upload image using Retrofit2 (PATCH Request)

Tags: android, file-upload, retrofit2, multipart

I know how to upload an image to server using POST request:

```
// AuthService.kt
@Multipart
@POST("auth/update")
fun updateInfo(
        @Header("Authorization") token: String,
        @Part("fullName") fullName: RequestBody,
        @Part("address") address: RequestBody,
        @Part avatarPic: MultipartBody.Part?
)

// Activity
val file = File(...
val reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file)
val avatarPic = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("avatarPic", file.name, reqFile)
val fullName = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "Saman")
val address = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "Malekan")
authService.updateInfo(token, fullName, address, avatarPic)...
```

I want to send this request using PATCH method but I can't. I seems that it doesn't recognize fields. how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.
I send the request via `"Method Spoofing"`. I just changed the method in `AuthService.kt` to:

```
@Multipart
@POST("auth/update")
fun updateInfo(
        @Header("Authorization") token: String,
        @Part("fullName") fullName: RequestBody,
        @Part("address") address: RequestBody,
        @Part avatarPic: MultipartBody.Part?,
        @Part("_method") method: RequestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "PATCH")
)
```

The `_method` field inside the request cause the server that act to request as `PATCH` request.